# Why does my element not show when I use @media?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .artists, .shop, .releases, .dates, .row.stars {
     display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .topings {
     display: block;
  }
}

.topings {
   display: none;
}
```

What i'm trying to make appear is `.topings`, it is a p class.

```
<p class="topings">ARTISTS   SHOP   RELEASES   DATES</p>
```

For some reason display none and block dont work,  maybe i messed up on something? Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to use `{}` after the `@media` and put everything inside it. Your CSS is lacking `{}` for the `@media` queries. Also change the order - start with smaller `max-width` and then go for the bigger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your rules:

```
.topings {
   display: none;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .artists, .shop, .releases, .dates, .row.stars {
     display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .topings {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to add `{}` for the `@media`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your code.

1. `@media` queries must have curly braces `{}` around the styles which go inside it. *(In your most recent edit, you have now fixed this yourself, so you can ignore this point.)*
2. Styles later in the document override earlier ones. Therefore the most specific `@media` query **must** come last in the document. At the moment, `display: none;` is applied to all screen sizes and comes last in the document, so it will override everything else.

Here is the full corrected code:

```css
.topings {
   display: none;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .artists, .shop, .releases, .dates, .row.stars {
     display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .topings {
     display: block;
  }
}
```